# Python - Pandas to split CSV VERTICALLY

Tags: python, pandas

Browsed forums here but nothing that will split by a column using pandas. I have columns (in csv)

```
Name A1 A2 A3.......A7
```

Name is "unique identifier" and needs to be in both files after split.

Therefore, I need to split this into the following two output files as csv

```
Name A1 A2 A3 A4
Name A5 A6 A7
```

There are many examples to split horizontally and those worked for me. But vertical split is what I am looking for. Ideally using Pandas library. Thanks!

EDITED (Sorry if the pictures do not render well. I am new to this forum)

Input File

[Input File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kboL7.png)

Output File 1
[Output File 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqlUA.png)

Output File 2

[Output File 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vdEB.png)

Comment: kindly share a couple of rows from your dataframe, with expected output as well

Comment: why not use `df[['Name', 'A1', 'A2']]` and `df[['Name', 'A6', 'A7']]`

Comment: @mujjiga Thank YOU! This worked like a charm. I should have started with thinking simple I guess. I feel so silly.  :-)

Comment: @mujjiga Please add your comment as an answer so that it can be marked as a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly select out the columns you want from pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 

# Define a dictionary containing data 
data = {'Name':['ABC', 'XYZ'], 
        'Gender':['M', 'F'], 
        'A1':[98, 100], 
        'A2':[56, 54],
        'A3':[81, 100],
        'A4':[94, 99],
        'A5':[100, 100],
        'A6':[100, 100],
        'A7':[100, 100]} 

# Convert the dictionary into DataFrame  
df = pd.DataFrame(data) 

df1 = df[['Name', 'Gender', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']]
df2 = df[['Name', 'Gender', 'A5', 'A6', 'A7']]
```

Result

df1:

```
Name    Gender  A1  A2  A3  A4
0   ABC M   98  56  81  94
1   XYZ F   100 54  100 99
```

df2:

```
Name    Gender  A5  A6  A7
0   ABC M   100 100 100
1   XYZ F   100 100 100
```

You can then export these files as csv using simple `to_csv()` command:

```
df1.to_csv('file1.csv')
df2.to_csv('file2.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to solve my question. I did not want to hard code the values, so I used @mujjiga solution above. However, I am sure your code snippet will come in handy at some point! Thanks again!

Comment: You don't need to hardcode the values. I did it just for showing the results!

Comment: Naman Deep - I guess I misunderstood. Sorry. Super new to python. How would you create the data dict using the csv as an input? That is the part that confused me. Thank you!

Comment: You don't need that step. You would directly use pd.read_csv() instead!

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Thank you. Gotcha! Thanks so much for the clarification. it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas column indexing

```
df[['Name', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'A4']] and df[['Name', 'A6', 'A7']]
```